ADP Mass File Download for I-9 Forms
I was wondering if anyone knows how to perform a mass download of I-9 forms with a script? Currently, it needs to be done manually for over 400 employees. Thank you in advance!
I have not tried anything yet as I was unable to find anything through a search on here.
